# MYSQL 5.7 ERROR 1215 Foreign key + Fulltext Key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, full-text-search, mysql-5.7

I have following problem.

I have sql file created by dump that contains code:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

/*SOME MORE SCRIPTS*/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `avalues`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;

CREATE TABLE `avalues` (
  `AVALUES_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AVALUES_MVALUES_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `AVALUES_OBJECT_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `AVALUES_VALUE` LONGTEXT,
  `AVALUES_RANG` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `AVALUES_VALUE_NUM` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVALUES_VALUE_DATE` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVALUES_VALUE_TIME` TIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVALUES_TOBJECT_ID` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AVALUES_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_AVALUES_MVALUES_OBJECT_RANG` (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`,`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`,`AVALUES_RANG`),
  KEY `I_AVALUES_MVALUES` (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`),
  KEY `I_AVALUES_OBJECT` (`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`),
  KEY `I_AVALUES_MVALUES_NUM` (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`,`AVALUES_VALUE_NUM`),
  KEY `I_AVALUES_MVALUES_DATE` (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`,`AVALUES_VALUE_DATE`),
  KEY `i_avalues_object_mvalues` (`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`,`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`),
  KEY `I_AVALUES_VALUE` (`AVALUES_VALUE`(255)),
  KEY `I_AVALUES_MVALUES_VALUE` (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`,`AVALUES_VALUE`(255)),
  KEY `i_avalues_tobject_value` (`AVALUES_TOBJECT_ID`,`AVALUES_VALUE`(255))
  , KEY `i_avalues_object_mvalues_value` (`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`,`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`,`AVALUES_VALUE`(255))
   , CONSTRAINT `FK_AVALUES_MVALUES_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`) REFERENCES `mask_values` (`MVALUES_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
   , CONSTRAINT `FK_AVALUES_OBJECT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`) REFERENCES `object` (`OBJECT_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
   , FULLTEXT KEY `I_AVALUES_VALUE_FULLTEXT` (`AVALUES_VALUE`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=3463676 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*SOME MORE SCRIPTS*/

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

I am using **InnoDB** engine.

Before when i had mysql version **5.6.5-m8-log** everything was OK and all scripts has been processed correctly with mysql.

Today i updated mysql to version **5.7.9-log** and when i want tu run these scripts, table avalues is not created.

I get Following error: 
**Error Code: 1215
Cannot add foreign key constraint**

When i take out from scripts line

```
FULLTEXT KEY `I_AVALUES_VALUE_FULLTEXT` (`AVALUES_VALUE`)
```

**OR** both lines

```
, CONSTRAINT `FK_AVALUES_MVALUES_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`) REFERENCES `mask_values` (`MVALUES_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
, CONSTRAINT `FK_AVALUES_OBJECT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`) REFERENCES `object` (`OBJECT_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

table is created correctly. But it seems that if all three lines are together, it causes mentioned error.

I have read that before mysql version 5.6 these two keys (foreign and fulltext) could not be together in one table. But i am using mysql version 5.7.9. I tried to google problem but i cant find solution that would work for me.

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug: [Bug #78955: Import Dump with InnoDB Fulltext Index and Constraint fails](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78955)

Try the following change, first create the referenced tables:

```sql
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `avalues`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mask_values`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `object`;

CREATE TABLE `mask_values` (
  `MVALUES_ID` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `object` (
  `OBJECT_ID` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `avalues` (
  `AVALUES_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AVALUES_MVALUES_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `AVALUES_OBJECT_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `AVALUES_VALUE` LONGTEXT,
  `AVALUES_RANG` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `AVALUES_VALUE_NUM` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVALUES_VALUE_DATE` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVALUES_VALUE_TIME` TIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVALUES_TOBJECT_ID` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AVALUES_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_AVALUES_MVALUES_OBJECT_RANG` (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`,`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`,`AVALUES_RANG`),
  KEY `I_AVALUES_MVALUES` (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`),
  KEY `I_AVALUES_OBJECT` (`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`),
  KEY `I_AVALUES_MVALUES_NUM` (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`,`AVALUES_VALUE_NUM`),
  KEY `I_AVALUES_MVALUES_DATE` (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`,`AVALUES_VALUE_DATE`),
  KEY `i_avalues_object_mvalues` (`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`,`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`),
  KEY `I_AVALUES_VALUE` (`AVALUES_VALUE`(255)),
  KEY `I_AVALUES_MVALUES_VALUE` (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`,`AVALUES_VALUE`(255)),
  KEY `i_avalues_tobject_value` (`AVALUES_TOBJECT_ID`,`AVALUES_VALUE`(255)),
  KEY `i_avalues_object_mvalues_value` (`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`,`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`,`AVALUES_VALUE`(255)),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_AVALUES_MVALUES_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`) REFERENCES `mask_values` (`MVALUES_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_AVALUES_OBJECT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`) REFERENCES `object` (`OBJECT_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FULLTEXT KEY `I_AVALUES_VALUE_FULLTEXT` (`AVALUES_VALUE`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*
CREATE TABLE `mask_values` (
  `MVALUES_ID` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `object` (
  `OBJECT_ID` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
*/

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

mysql> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> /*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> /*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> /*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> /*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `avalues`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mask_values`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `object`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `mask_values` (
    ->   `MVALUES_ID` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    -> ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `object` (
    ->   `OBJECT_ID` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    -> ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `avalues` (
    ->   `AVALUES_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `AVALUES_MVALUES_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `AVALUES_OBJECT_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `AVALUES_VALUE` LONGTEXT,
    ->   `AVALUES_RANG` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `AVALUES_VALUE_NUM` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `AVALUES_VALUE_DATE` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `AVALUES_VALUE_TIME` TIME DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `AVALUES_TOBJECT_ID` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`AVALUES_ID`),
    ->   UNIQUE KEY `UK_AVALUES_MVALUES_OBJECT_RANG` (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`,`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`,`AVALUES_RANG`),
    ->   KEY `I_AVALUES_MVALUES` (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`),
    ->   KEY `I_AVALUES_OBJECT` (`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`),
    ->   KEY `I_AVALUES_MVALUES_NUM` (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`,`AVALUES_VALUE_NUM`),
    ->   KEY `I_AVALUES_MVALUES_DATE` (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`,`AVALUES_VALUE_DATE`),
    ->   KEY `i_avalues_object_mvalues` (`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`,`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`),
    ->   KEY `I_AVALUES_VALUE` (`AVALUES_VALUE`(255)),
    ->   KEY `I_AVALUES_MVALUES_VALUE` (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`,`AVALUES_VALUE`(255)),
    ->   KEY `i_avalues_tobject_value` (`AVALUES_TOBJECT_ID`,`AVALUES_VALUE`(255)),
    ->   KEY `i_avalues_object_mvalues_value` (`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`,`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`,`AVALUES_VALUE`(255)),
    ->   CONSTRAINT `FK_AVALUES_MVALUES_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`) REFERENCES `mask_values` (`MVALUES_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ->   CONSTRAINT `FK_AVALUES_OBJECT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`) REFERENCES `object` (`OBJECT_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ->   FULLTEXT KEY `I_AVALUES_VALUE_FULLTEXT` (`AVALUES_VALUE`)
    -> ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> /*
   /*> CREATE TABLE `mask_values` (
   /*>   `MVALUES_ID` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
   /*> ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
   /*> 
   /*> CREATE TABLE `object` (
   /*>   `OBJECT_ID` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
   /*> ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
   /*> */

mysql> /*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> /*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> /*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> /*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I'm looking for the cause of the behavior.

**UPDATE**

When you try `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` (See [13.7.5.15 SHOW ENGINE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-engine.html)) after creating the table, you can read the following:

```sql
...
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2000-01-01 00:00:01 0x901ffb40 Error in foreign key constraint of table test/avalues:
 FOREIGN KEY (`AVALUES_MVALUES_ID`) REFERENCES `mask_values` (`MVALUES_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_AVALUES_OBJECT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`) REFERENCES `object` (`OBJECT_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FULLTEXT KEY `I_AVALUES_VALUE_FULLTEXT` (`AVALUES_VALUE`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8:
Cannot resolve table name close to:
 (`MVALUES_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_AVALUES_OBJECT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`AVALUES_OBJECT_ID`) REFERENCES `object` (`OBJECT_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FULLTEXT KEY `I_AVALUES_VALUE_FULLTEXT` (`AVALUES_VALUE`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

It works the way when i first create other tables but i will use rather older version of MySQL. I am not limited to new version and I work only with sql file which is given to me so it is easier to install older version than each time make changes.

Anyway once again thanks for the answer